# Why 'image_dataset_from directory' (keras, tensorflow) is returning an object of BatchDataset = None?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to create a **LeNet5** for the images supplied in [this link](http://chaladze.com/l5/).

In order to upload the training and test sets, I use

```
tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory:
    train_set = image_dataset_from_directory('Linnaeus_5_32X32/train',
                                        labels='inferred',
                                        label_mode = 'categorical',
                                        color_mode = 'grayscale',
                                        batch_size=batch_size,
                                        image_size = (image_rows,image_cols),
                                        shuffle=True,
                                        seed=1997)

    test_set = image_dataset_from_directory('Linnaeus_5_32X32/test',
                                            labels='inferred',
                                            label_mode = 'categorical',
                                            color_mode = 'grayscale',
                                            batch_size = batch_size,
                                            image_size = (image_rows,image_cols),
                                            shuffle=True,
                                            seed=1997)
```

This should returns a `tf.data.Dataset` object that is a tuple (images, labels), where images has shape (`batch_size, image_size[0], image_size[1], num_channels`), and labels follows the format (batch_size, num_classes).

However, this is what I get, printed on the screen:

```
  Found 6000 files belonging to 5 classes.
  Found 2000 files belonging to 5 classes.
```

This is correct because I have 6000 train images and 2000 test images. But when I inspect, for example, the training_set I get:

```
<BatchDataset shapes: ((None, 32, 32, 1), (None, 5)), types: (tf.float32, tf.float32)>
```

That is, batch_size = None when it should be 6000.

What does this mean? How can I fix it?

Comment: Also, how could I divide the training and test sets into the new variables x_training (images), y_training (labels) and x_test (images) and y_test (labels) ?

Comment: None just means variable, it does not have to be equal the the number of samples at this point.

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference between the Batch Size and the total training samples. If you have 6000 images for training, you can train your model with 1 batch of size 6000, 100 batches of size 60, and so on.

`batch_size = None` basically means that any batch size is acceptable for your model. The batch size is set during your training. In Keras, you can set `batch_size` as an argument to `model.fit()`. Keras will calculate the required number of batches depending on your specified `batch_size`

For more info on `fit` arguments, you can go [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit)

Comment: Yes, you are right, thank you so much. I will fix that in fit(). But, how could I divide this object if it accepts no actions with .shape()? How can I split this objects into two different variables: images (x_train) and labels (y_train)?

Comment: I don't think you need to split your dataset to Images and labels (it's already handled in `image_dataset_from_directory`. After you build and compile your model, you can just:

`model.fit(train_set, epochs=epochs, validation_data=test_set)`

Comment: You can check [this example](https://keras.io/examples/vision/image_classification_from_scratch/) for an end-to-end image classification task in Keras